# How do I keep only the lowest price item from Scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

The website I'm scraping has multiple products with the same ID but different prices. I want to keep only the lowest price version.

```
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem

class DuplicatesPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.ids_seen = dict()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        if item['ID'] in self.ids_seen:
            if item['sale_price']>self.ids_seen[item['ID']]:
                raise DropItem("Duplicate item found: %s" % item)
        else:
            self.ids_seen.add(item['ID'])
            return item
```

So this code should drop items that are a higher price than those seen before but I can't figure out how to update a previously scraped item if the price is lower.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
import urlparse
import re

class ExampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'name'
    allowed_domains = ['domain1','domain2']
    start_urls = ['url1','url2']

    def parse(self, response):
        for href in response.css('div.catalog__main__content .c-product-card__name::attr("href")').extract():
            url = urlparse.urljoin(response.url, href) 
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_product)

    # follow pagination links
        href = response.css('.c-paging__next-link::attr("href")').extract_first()
        if href is not None:
            url = urlparse.urljoin(response.url, href) 
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)
    def parse_product(self, response):
       # process the response here (omitted because it's long and doesn't add anything)
        yield {
            'product-name': name,
            'price-sale': price_sale,
            'price-regular': price_regular[:-1],
            'raw-sku': raw_sku,
            'sku': sku.replace('_','/'),
            'img': response.xpath('//img[@class="itm-img"]/@src').extract()[-1],
            'description': response.xpath('//div[@class="product-description__block"]/text()').extract_first(),
            'url' : response.url,
        }
```

Comment: What is website you are scraping? and what is code of Spider?

Comment: @Umair I can't tell you the website but I have included the spider code. Not sure it applies to the question but here it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you know the product Id's before you start? If so then normal website behaviour would allow you to search price low>high thus you could scrape the first item returned for each product Id which would avoid the need for any pipeline processing.

If you don't then you could do a two step process, first searching through all of the products to get the Id's, then doing the process above for each Id.

Comment: I don't know the IDs but starting on the page which is sorted with prices low to high is a great idea! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with pipelines since it's ongoing. In other words it returns items as it goes without waiting for spider to finish.

However if you have a database you can get around this issue:

In semy-pseudo code:

```
class DbPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.connection = # connect to your database

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        db_item = self.connection.get(item['ID'])
        if item['price'] < db_item['price']:
            self.connection.remove(item['ID'])
            self.connection.add(item)
        return item
```

You'll still get unfiltered results in scrapy output, but your database will be ordered.
Personal recommendation would be to use document based database, key to value database such as `redis`.

Comment: Is there no option to do this via a custom item exporter at all? I want to run this on scrapinghub and I already have a system set up to use their API.

Comment: @TahaAttari You potentially could, but that means keeping all of your data in a buffer before writing it to a file which is a bad idea unless your crawls are very small.